# How to integrate findbugs 1.3.4 plugin with Myeclipse 8.0M1 offline

Tags: integration, findbugs, myeclipse

At my work place I don't have access to the internet, so I downloaded findbugs plugin version 1.3.4 (jar file) to integrate with Myeclipse version 8.0M1. I tried to integrate it by browsing the jar file from local archive but it is saying no repository found. I tried by copying the jar file to eclipse install directory in plug-in folder also but of no use.

Comment: Post the error, perhaps post a screenshot of your workspace? If you can't post an image, post it in the comments

Comment: I used the following process: You can also manually download the plugin from the following link: http://prdownloads.sourceforge.net/findbugs/edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugin.eclipse_3.0.1.20150306.zip?download. Extract it in Eclipse's "plugins" subdirectory. (So <eclipse_install_dir>/plugins/edu.umd.cs.findbugs.plugin.eclipse_3.0.1.20150306/findbugs.png should be the path to the FindBugs logo.)

Comment: A general remark: reading your question was like jumping back in time - nobody is using myeclipse anymore. Furthermore you are using a 6 year old version which is deprecated for a long time now. Also findbugs 1.X is way old - in the meantime findbugs 2.X and now even 3.X has been released. Consider "returning" to our time by upgrading your environment. Use a newer IDE and findbugs version and benefit from many bugfixes and new features...

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of Lonzak's personal opinion, MyEclipse is still widely used but release 8 is very old and based on a very old release of eclipse.

However, it looks like you're using an incorrect method to install the plug-in, though you don't give exact steps. The error you mention indicates that the file you browsed to isn't a valid eclipse update site (assumed to be archived as a file, in this case). That seems right, if you've downloaded the plug-in from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/findbugs/files/findbugs%20eclipse%20plugin/1.3.4/).

Instead, extract the zip file to the dropins folder. In later releases of MyEclipse, the dropins folder would be in the installation folder for the profile (i.e. not the Common folder but the folder for the specific ME release, where the myeclipse.exe file is). I assume it is in the same place in release 8 but can't check.

I don't know which release of FindBugs is compatible with ME 8, so you're on your own there.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i can't suggest that to my client. My job is only to test their application. Can i try any other version of findbugs plugin.